# Show Plot and input dialogue in the same figure or at the same time [ Python Matplotlib Pyplot PyQt4 ]

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt4

I'm interested to have a plot and an input dialogue in the same figure using pyplot and matplotlib with qt4 backend.
I've tried to search in the matplotlib widgets library, but I couldn't find anything suitable.
The ideal result is having plot and input dialogue in the same figure, alternatively It might be ok to have both at the same time. 
Does anybody has got an advice?

Here there's a simplified example of what I would like to do, the plot and the input dialogue works, but the comes one after the other.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PyQt4 import QtGui

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

text,ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter a number:')
n=float(text)
print n #here I just print, but n will be passed to another function for successive steps.
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at the embedding example?

Comment: @tcaswell : yes, I have checked here: [link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html), but it works for embedding to plots, and unfortunately i do not understand how to do the same thing with a plot and an input dialogue...